# Display rows from MYSQL query as columns in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MYSQL database storing levels for students for each terms work.

I'm fine creating the php page, with query etc and very comfortable with the hmtl/css required to create tables. I have a basic understanding of arrays.

Where I am struggling is how to take each students data and display it in columns in the html table.

Previously my assessment table in the database had multiple colums - aut7, spr7, sum7 etc so it was easy to display in an html table. However I have been trying to make the database more effective so am now storing each assessment as a separate record - database is much better set-up but has thrown up the following problem (well lack of knowledge on my part!!)

A simple example of what I mean is as follows:

This is the result of a query:

```
student_id   term    level
  1          aut7      3b
  1          spr7      3a
  1          sum7      4c
  2          aut7      3a
  2          spr7      4c
  2          sum7      4b
```

I would like it in displayed in my html/css table as follows:

```
 Student      Aut7      Spr7     Sum7
   1           3b        3a       4c
   2           3a        4c       4a
```

If anyone could help a relative newcomer to PHP/MySQL I would be very grateful.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of links over to the right, under **"Related"** that are sure to help.

Comment: 1) run query 2) suck query results into PHP array 3) spit array out into html. if you build the array properly while sucking in the query results, spitting it out into a column-based html layout is easy.

Comment: Here: http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php - After Googling 0.45 seconds "display database results in html table". - *"About 1,440,000 results (0.45 seconds)"* And, you're welcome.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did a hefty amount of google searching but could not find the specific issue I was having. I always try to solve myself before posting on a forum. I'm quite happy displaying database results in an html table - just not this specific scenario. The David Walsh example you kindly linked to was not appropriate in this case. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for taking the time to reply - solved using Rafa's suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. Then, the answer given below was exactly what you were looking for then. @Dunks - You did mention "in HTML table" so I was under the impression that's what you were looking for. HTML and SQL are 2 different animals altogether ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pivot your results. Unfortunately MySQL does have `PIVOT` but you can build a query like this to achieve the same results

```
SELECT student_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN term = 'aut7' THEN level END) Aut7,
  MAX(CASE WHEN term = 'spr7' THEN level END) Spr7,
  MAX(CASE WHEN term = 'sum7' THEN level END) Sum7
FROM student_terms
GROUP BY student_id
```

See demo in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/989874/7)

Comment: Thats magic Rafa - my actual query to produce the data set in my example contains inner joins but i was able to take your example and work it into my query. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey Rafa - I did try to vote up the answer but as a newbie on Stack I can't do that until I have earn some 'reputation points' it seems. I will make sure I come back and vote it up as soon as I am able.