# MySQL - Select Query with junction table to one row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

i have the following tables:

```
**entries**
entry_id | date | engineer | project

**entries_allowanes_map**
entry_id | allowance_id

**allowances**
allowance_id | allowance_name
```

I want to create a SELECT query that will give the following result:

```
entry_id | date | engineer | project | allowance_name1 | allowance_name2 | allowance_name_n...
```

The queries I have tried return a row for each allowance an entry has registered with. I want just one row with all allowances attached to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use `JOIN` or `GROUP`.

Comment: No one is guiding you to the good road, the road is to tranpose your rows into columns, i dont know about mysql but this can be accomplished in SQL Server with a PIVOT take a look to this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510657/pivot-table-using-mysql I think that is what you want

Comment: @Mr. is right. You want to PIVOT your rows for columns. In MySQL there is not PIVOT but you can accomplish with CASE and aggregate functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963378/display-rows-from-mysql-query-as-columns-in-html-table The problem I can see here is that there is not a fix number of rows we can pivot manually `allowance_name_n`. A dynamic SQL statement will do the job (check the link that @Mr. posted)

Comment: @Rafa that's right, the post I linked shows an example of dynamic rows, he just need to translate it to his needs, I'm on the rush right now but I hope that helps him out, I'm almost sure anyone with time can make a sqlfiddle for hint, and also will be an excellent for SO, the realted Fildde in the link is this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d020b/4

Comment: Please show the query that you have written to get one entry on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose doing this with `group_concat()`.  It doesn't put the values in separate columns, but it does put everything for a given entry on one row:

```
select e.entry_id, e.date, e.engineer, e.project, 
       group_concat(a.allowance_name) as allowances
from entries e join
     entries_allowances_map f
     on e.entry_id = eam.entry_id 
     allowances a
     on eam.allowance_id = a.allowance_id
group by e.entry_id;
```

Comment: Is there anyway i could modify this query so that it still returns a result if allowances is null? Thanks

Comment: @user3343734 . . . I am not sure exactly what you mean.  Can you ask another question with sample data and desired results?

Comment: For example if I ran your suggested query with added parameter 'where entry_id = 1'. If that entry was linked to a set of allowances then it works great. However if it wasn't linked to any allowances then it would return no results. Even though entry_id 1 existed. I'd like it to return an entry even if no allowances are linked.

Comment: @user3343734 . . . Add the condition to an `on` clause rather than to a `where` clause, change the joins to `left join`s, and you might need `coalesce()` in the `group_concat()`.

Comment: The left join did it. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that I got:

It outputs your expected results in different columns:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      '(SELECT max(CASE WHEN AL.ALLOWANCE_ID = ''',
      ALLOWANCE_ID,
      ''' THEN 1 END) AS `',
      ALLOWANCE_ID, '` FROM entries_allowanes_map AL WHERE E.ENTRY_ID = AL.ENTRY_ID ) AS `',
      ALLOWANCE_NAME, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM allowances;



SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT E.ENTRY_ID, E.DATE, E.ENGINEER, E.PROJECT, ', @sql, ' 
           FROM entries as e');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e01a5/2)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM entries as e
INNER JOIN entries_allowanes_map as a ON e.entry_id=e.entry_id
INNER JOIN allownces as al ON al.allownce_id=a.allowance_id
```